# how to change size of scrollView in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am using same UIScrollView to show different images in DetailViewController, and I want to change UIScrollView size for different Images, how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the size like with any other view:

```
myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

refer a below code.

```
//left Area Extension
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, scrollView.frame.size.width*2, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//right Area Extension
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*2, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```